# How can I add both image and string in Tabs in LWUIT-1.5?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I am trying to add both image and string in Tabs in LWUIT-1.5. Anyway both are comes in UI but the text is coming at bottom of the image. So, I need to add both in same place like overlapping the image.

```
Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
tabs.addTab("Text", Image, Component);
```

can any one help us ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a background image for the tabs not an icon (which is what that API is for), you should modify the style's for the Tab UIID in the resource editor and set the image background you want.

Answer (score 0):

**That is not possible without using resource editor**. You set either image or text. If you set both, it takes image as icon and text as title automatically.

Create theme in resource editor by setting the background image for Tabs and apply the theme in your app.